# Python unable to decompress gzip file

Tags: python, gzip

I have a file with a special file ending (.dsx) that basically is a gzip'ed XML file. I am able to decompress that file using

```
$ gzip -S .dsx -d -c file.dsx
<prints my XML to the console>
```

I'm trying to do the same thing with Python:

```
import sys
import gzip

def main():

    file_path = sys.argv[1]
    
    with gzip.open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        file_content = f.read()
        # ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<truncated>\decode-dsx.py", line 17, in <module>
    main()
  File "<truncated>\decode-dsx.py", line 13, in main
    file_content = f.read()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\gzip.py", line 301, in read
    return self._buffer.read(size)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\_compression.py", line 118, in readall    
    while data := self.read(sys.maxsize):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\gzip.py", line 488, in read
    if not self._read_gzip_header():
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\gzip.py", line 436, in _read_gzip_header  
    raise BadGzipFile('Not a gzipped file (%r)' % magic)
gzip.BadGzipFile: Not a gzipped file (b'PK'
```

I also tried calling the module directly, by adding the `.gz` line ending, and calling:

```
python -m gzip -d .\file.gz
```

It produces the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jasonharper's hint, it was indeed just a regular zip file.

```
import sys
import zipfile
import os

def main():

    file_path = sys.argv[1]
    file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)

    with zipfile.ZipFile(file_path, mode="r") as archive:
        with archive.open(f'{file_name}.xml') as myfile:
            print(myfile.read())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```